# Copy content from space in Alfresco Explorer

Tags: java, alfresco

I have an Alfresco app and I create some nested Spaces, and now I want to copy some content on the last space to another one.

At the moment I'm searching the nodeRefs of the children spaces, and then I'm creating it in the new places but when I arrive to content I don't know how to copy it or copy his data to create in the destination space.

This is a little diagram to show what I want to do:

```
OriginalFolder
|______OriginalSubFolder
       |_________OriginalContent
```

And now want to do this

```
DestinationFolder
|______Copy of OriginalSubFolder
       |_______Copy of OriginalContent
```

At now I only can clone the "OriginalSubFolder" listing the Alfresco's `nodeRef`   and copying all of their properties.

Maybe, the code of createContent can help

I tried with:

```
fileInfo = getFileFolderService().copy(childNodeRef, nodeContenidoNuevo, nombreContenido);
```

But don't copy the content (an image in this case). When I click in the content Alfresco show this:

```
Contenido del nodo, faltante: 
   nodo: workspace://SpacesStore/72951dc4-f59a-4389-b020-6b2eef8cd9d3 
   lector: null  
Sírvase contactar al administrador del sistema.
```

PD: Sorry, I know my English is pathetic...

Comment: Is the [Alfresco CopyService](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/CopyService.html) not what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I'd suggest the [FileFolderService.copy](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/model/FileFolderService.html) method.

It's quite easy to use, just the provide the source NodeRef, the Parent target NodeRef and the new name.

Comment: When I'm trying to access the copy shows this:

`Contenido del nodo, faltante: 
   nodo: workspace://SpacesStore/72951dc4-f59a-4389-b020-6b2eef8cd9d3 
   lector: null  
Sírvase contactar al administrador del sistema.`

I'm copiying using this:
`fileInfo = getFileFolderService().copy(childNodeRef, nodeRefNewContent, contentName);`

Comment: Can you edit your question with the full stacktrace? (Check alfresco.log or similar). Without that it's hard to know what's wrong

Comment: @Gagravarr I edited, my post, alfresco.log and catalina.out  don't show errors.

Comment: btw not everybody understands Spanish :). The log states that node with id workspace://SpacesStore/72951dc4-f59a-4389-b020-6b2eef8cd9d3 is missing. Can you check if it exists?

Comment: Oh, sorry, The node exists but not have content.

Comment: Finally the problem was that I'm Copying the wrong node.